# Интерпретация слова прототип в статьях о js

Tags: javascript

Прочел по этой теме много статей и из книг вычитывал главы, соответствующие теме, но как бы мне самому не было смешно, разобраться до конца у меня не получилось. Не получилось из-за
того, что я не совсем понимаю определения "для всех инстенсов будет один и тот же прототип".   Вот что это имеют ввиду?

1. Данной фразой сравнивают прототип с классом, говоря об 
   его абстракции.
2. Или понимать нужно так, как написано?

Вот что самое запутывающие, что, как мне кажется, эту фразу применяют и к первому, и ко второму. Как, например, начинающие программисты говорят "создал класс", хотя уже созданное - это объект, экземпляр, сущность.

**Обновление**

Тогда у меня ещё один вопрос:

```
function Test( ){}

Test.prototype = {
    n: 10
};

var a = new Test( );
console.log( a.n ); // это я от куда читаю?

a.n = 15; // а здесь куда записываю?
```

Статью читал уже.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript, это язык, в котором используется ООП не на основе классов, а на основе прототипов. Так называемое [прототипное программирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Прототипное_программирование). Прототип - это объект, реально существующий, на основе которого создается новый объект и наследуются его свойства.

Как вы понимаете, он одновременно является как экземпляром (он в отличие от класса существует, а не просто описан), так и прототипом в зависимости от того, как вы его используете.

Давайте на примерах.

Здесь объект objA выступает в качестве экземпляра объекта Object, а Object в качестве прототипа:

```
var objA = new Object();
objA.sayHello = "Hello ;)";
```

Теперь сделаем одну хитрую вещь:

```
var objB = {}
objB.__proto__ = objA;
objB.sayHello //выведет Hello ;)
```

Здесь мы создали объект b, со свойствами объекта а, то есть в данном случае объект a выступил прототипом. Получается своеобразная иерархия:

```
a.__proto__ = Object
b.__proto__ = a
```

Хотя objA является существующими экземпляром Object, он также является прототипом для объекта objB, для которого он указан как прототип. Здесь я напрямую указал объект objA как прототип, и все изменения в нем будут отражены и на objB.

P.S. Да, что-то я немного подзабыл JavaScript. При использовании ключевого слова new с функциями происходит примерно то же самое, создается новый объект с прототипом функции. Можно еще [вот эту статейку](http://habrahabr.ru/post/120193/) почитать для понимания.

---

UPD.

Область видимость переменных такая: если свойство не найдено в текущем объекте, оно ищется в прототипе. Если нет в прототипе, оно ищется в прототипе прототипа и так далее вверх по иерархии объектов, пока не упрется в потолок.

```
function Test( ){}

Test.prototype = {
    n: 10
};

var a = new Test( );
```

В данном случае у самого объекта "а" нет свойства n, поэтому оно его находит в прототипе:

```
a.__proto__.n //a.n на самом деле нет
```

Но если мы пишем a.n = 15, то пишем в текущий объект и прототип перекрывается.

```
a.n = 15
a.n //равно 15, Он находит свойство в самом "а" и не лезет в прототипы.  
a.__proto__.n //по прежнему 10
```

Comment: Про ps не понял... Вы хотите сказать, что при создании new Test создается КОПИЯ объекта-прототипа Test.prototype?

Comment: @vas, вот именно внутреннее устройство иерархии при использовании new я и забыл, как оказывается. Нет, создается новый объект и его прототипом становится Test.prototype (вроде он, если память не изменяет), но сам Test.prototype точно не копируется. Уберу из ответа для устранения неоднозначностей.

Comment: То есть, когда мы задаем значение равное 15, мы пишем не в объект-прототип, а в объект, который возвращает конструктор при создании?  
И тогда получается, что а.[это приватная область видимости] для тех, кто на одном уровне, но публичная для потомков объекта а?

Comment: 1. Да, если пишем, то уже в объект возвращенный конструктором, перекрывая доступ в прототипы.

2. Тут не совсем понял, если мы не можем обратиться к a[приватная область видимости], то и потомки к ней не смогут обратиться. Ведь они так же будут искать это свойство, как если бы вручную из программы вводить a[...].

Comment: @Alex Krass, про второе я немножечко сглупил, подумав, что не найдя в самом объекте унаследованного от "a", взор интерпретатора подёт на объект родителя. А на самом деле,
 наследование же прототипное, и не найдя его, фокус передвинется в прототип родителя.
Спасибо Вам!