# Прототипное программирование ?

Tags: javascript

```
Прототипное программирование — это модель ООП которая не использует классы, 
а вместо этого сначала выполняет поведение класса и затем использует 
его повторно (эквивалент наследования в языках на базе классов), 
декорируя (или расширяя) существующие объекты прототипы. (Также 
называемое бесклассовое, прототипно-ориентированное, или экземплярно-
ориентированное программирование.)
```

Прошу помощи в объяснении данного текста.. Пытаюсь перейти паралельно на веб, сложно осваивается подход к Java Script после Java.

Что такое прототипное программирование ?

"**это модель ООП которая не использует классы, 
а вместо этого сначала выполняет поведение класса**" Чего ???

С пониманием объектно ориентированного программирования нету проблем.

Comment: откуда взят этот текст?

Comment: Возможно дубликат вопроса: [Интерпретация слова прототип в статьях о js](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/372790/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8F%D1%85-%D0%BE-js/372800)

Comment: Как я его понял, хотя может я его не понял ... ваши классы просто уже наследованы от базовых классов, а базовые классы наследованы от своих базовых классов и так пока не придём к одному/нескольким классам, которые ни от кого не наследуются. Дерево ... При этом мы можем всё равно наследоваться от других классов, которые будут выступать в роли примесей ... Добавляя что-либо в прототип текущего класса (`HelloWorld.prototype.sayHi()`), мы говорим *не* `static` (`class HelloWorld {public function () {}}`), ...

Comment: ... а если просто присобачиваем в классу (`HelloWorld.sayHi()`), то говорим `static` (`class HelloWorld {public static function () {}}`). Как-то так, вроде ... бы.

Comment: Grundy - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: Хотя, наверное, лучше разобраться зачем нужен был велосипед, то есть в чём преимущество прототипного ООП перед классовым ООП ...

Comment: Roman Grinyov - в чём преимущество прототипного ООП перед классовым ООП ? Я с удовольствием послушаю =) !! А пока сам разбираюсь!

Comment: советую почитать Стоян Стефанов - Шаблоны JavaScript. Там есть несколько глав как раз посвященных этому вопросу.

Comment: @Maks.Burkov, так я сам бы послушал :)

Comment: @Roman Grinyov, нашол хорошее объяснение - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F4GL4M3wmuw&index=13&list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTaflXUL0v3TSm86nodn0c_u там с 12 видео!

Answer (score 10):

В отличие от большинства других ОО-языков (*Java*, *C#*), объектная система в **JavaScript** основана на прототипах, а не классах. Классы, которые вы знаете по таким языкам, как *Java*, технически не существуют в *JavaScript* (*JS*).

Вся иерархия объектов строиться на цепочках - прототипах. `Object.prototype` - объект, от которого "наследуются" все остальные объекты. Он содержит такие методы, как `toString()` или `valueOf().`Прототип у него равен `null`. Замечу, что `Object` это просто функция-конструктор для создания объектов:

```
typeof Object // 'function'
Object.prototype // объект Object {}
Object.prototype.__proto__ // 'null'
```

`prototype`, который используется в примере, применим только к функциям, а для созданных объектов используется `__proto__` (или `[[Prototype]]`).

Например, `Array`:

```
typeof Array // 'function'
Array.prototype.__proto__ === Object.prototype // true

var arr = [1,3]
arr.__proto__ // []
arr.__proto__ === Array.prototype // true

arr.__proto__.__proto__ // объект Object {}
arr.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype // true
```

Все методы массивов (`slice()`, `splice()`) хранятся в объекте `Array.prototype`, а прототип этого объекта узакывает на `Object.prototype`.

Получается: `arr -> Array.prototype -> Object.prototype -> null`

Так же с другими встроенными функциями-конструкторами, например `Function`, `Date`, `Number` и т.д.

---

Сейчас все усложнилось ещё тем, что в новом стандарте (ES6) разработчики *JS* ввели [`class`](https://learn.javascript.ru/es-class) – удобный «синтаксический сахар» для задания конструктора вместе с прототипом. Насколько мне известно, его ввели в том числе специально для разработчиков, которые хотят писать на *JS*, но которых смущает, что в них нет классов :). На самом деле `class` в *JS* это обычная функция:

```
class Car {}
typeof Car // 'function'
```

Поэтому я до сих пор считаю, что понятие *класс*  и *классическое наследование* немного некорректны в отношении JS.

---

Из плюсов прототипного наследования, наверно, это гибкость. Класс (например в *Java*) определяет все свойства для всех его экземпляров. Невозможно добавить свойства динамически во время выполнения. В тоже время в *JS* функция-конструктор определяет начальный набор свойств. Можно добавлять или удалять свойства динамически для отдельных объектов или сразу всем.

Возможно после использования интерфейсов/абстрактных классов в *Java* это покажется не плюсом, а минусом, но если этим уметь пользоваться, то потом этого не будет доставать в других языках.

```
// Функция конструктор
function Calculator () {}
Calculator.prototype.max = function (a, b) {
    return Math.max(a, b);
}

// Создадим два экземпляра (объекта)
var ins1 = new Calculator();
var ins2 = new Calculator();

// Протестируем метод max:
console.log(ins1.max(1, 5), ins2.max(1, 5)); // -> 5, 5


// Изменим метод прототипа, чтобы можно было выбирать макс. значение
// передавая сколько угодно параметров
Calculator.prototype.max = function () {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments);
    return Math.max.apply(null, args);
}

// Протестируем опять:
console.log(ins1.max(1, 5), ins2.max(1, 5)); // -> 5, 5
console.log(ins1.max(9, -5, 13), ins2.max(9, -5, 13)); // -> 13, 13
```

Мы так же могли поменять реализацию только для одного объекта (сделать как нужно в рамках задачи).

Повторюсь, `prototype`, который используется в примере, применим только к функциям, а для созданных объектов используется `__proto__` (или `[[Prototype]]`). Метод `max` будет находится в прототипе созданных объектов (`ins1.__proto__.max`), а прототипы у них указывают на один и тот же объект:

```
ins1.__proto__ === ins2.__proto__ // true
```

Интересный момент:

```
ins1.__proto__ // объект прототип
ins1.__proto__.constructor // function Calculator () {} - функция, с помощью который создаются объекты
ins1.__proto__.constructor.prototype // объект, который является прототипом
// Проверим?
ins1.__proto__.constructor.prototype === ins1.__proto__ // true
```

Другие достоинства, которые можно отметить: простота, мощность данного подхода, меньше избыточного кода, динамичность.

Если интересует момент, почему прототипное наследование в *JS* похоже на классическое (по синтаксису, например, использование оператора `new`), то это легко объяснить. Создатель *JS*, *Brendan Eich*, хотел чтобы *JavaScript* стал младшим братом *Java* и пытался его сделать максимально похожим синтаксически.

В общем я надеюсь, что вас ещё больше не запутал, просто нужно изучать изучать и ещё раз изучать :)

**UPD.:**

Пример использования "классов" из стандарта `ES6`.

```
class Auto {
    constructor(options) {
       this.name = options.name;
    }
    getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

const car = new Auto({ name: 'Lightning McQueen' });
car.getName(); // 'Lightning McQueen'
```

Все методы, объявленные в "классе" автоматически помещаются в прототип созданных объектов, а поля - в сам объект.

```
car.__proto__.getName // function getName() {return this.name;}
car.__proto__.name // undefined
car.__proto__.constructor // Auto

car.name // 'Lightning McQueen'
```

Ну и прототип протитипа `Auto` будет ссылкать на `Object.prototype`

```
car.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype // true
```

Код "класса" `Auto` (без методов) в стандарте ES5 будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
'use strict';    
function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { 
    if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { 
        throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); 
    } 
}

var Auto = function Auto(options) {
  _classCallCheck(this, Auto);

  this.name = options.name;
};
```

Обычная функция-конструктор с проверкой (за счет вызова `_classCallCheck`), чтобы нельзя вызывать `Auto` как функцию. Это все же класс :)

```
Auto() // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function(…)
```

Для создания методов используются `Object.defineProperty`, а посмотреть как работает *транспайлер* для методов (переводит код из ES6 в ES5 и не только) можно тут: https://babeljs.io/repl/ (*Babel* - один из самых популярных транспайлеров).

---

Рекомендую почитать:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model
2. https://learn.javascript.ru/prototype

Comment: мне кажется запутал :)

Comment: " Невозможно добавить свойства динамически во время выполнения. В тоже время в JS функция-конструктор определяет начальный набор свойств. Можно добавлять или удалять свойства динамически для отдельных объектов или сразу всем."  - Преимушеством JS прототипного наследование vs класического наследования является способность добавлять прототипы динамически и только?

Comment: Добавил преимущества в ответ, которые считаю самыми основными (Рекомендую почитать отличный ответ о плюсах прототипного наследования в js: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16872315/6554441). А вообще, это разные подходы для построения иерархии объектов, как и везде, есть свои плюсы и минусы.

Comment: Тем не менее - термин "класс" вполне применим к JS и мало отличается от обычного ООП. Если людям удобнее мыслить классами - зачем отказывать им в такой возможности, применимо к JS?

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр термин "класс" вполне применим, согласен. Можно создавать с помощью конструкций `class Foo extends Bar {}` "классы", и все будет прекрасно работать. Но на момент изучения прототипов в js и как они устроены, лучше абстрагироваться от понятия "классы" и классического наследования, чтобы самому не путаться.

Comment: В ответ можно добавить пример с объявлением простого класса на ES6 и результатом транспайла в ES5. Возможно, тем кто будет читать ответ это поможет разобраться.

Comment: @saaaaaaaaasha даже ещё до того как только мысли появились у разработчиков стандарта Ecma Script о ключевом слове `class` - порождающие функции называли классами в обиходе. Так что не знаю, мне кажется неверно воспринимать прототип чем-то особым, а думать в JS проще обычным ООП..)

Comment: @OlmerDale согласен, с какой строны посмотреть, и от какого определения класса отталкиваться.

Comment: Плюс про гибкость в статье подобран неверно. То что в Java нельзя добавить свойста в класс после его объявления является особенностью классов в Java и не связанно с классическим Классово-объектно ореинтированным подходом. Ruby, Python, PHP (через runkit) позволяют добавлять методы в классы в runtime, при этом используют классическое ООП.

Comment: Единственное что я не представляю как сделать в терминах классического ООП, это изменение "класса" объекта (смена прототипа, `__proto__ = `) после создания (к примеру d3.js, в 3 версии, делает это для выборок, для того чтоб они стали "похожи" на массивы). Но это считается не очень хорошим стилем, т.к. [негативно влияет на  возможность оптимизации кода браузером](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto).

Answer (score 3):

Классическое ООП и JS прототипы на самом деле имеют мало различий:

1. Любая функция в JS (кроме кратких - стрелочных функций ES6) является в терминологии ООП классом: к любой функции JS можно применять оператор `new`, что делает её конструктором. Это уже расширяет позицию ООП, в котором объекты конструируют не функции, а классы. Далее вместо термина функция - использую термин класс.
2. Прототип - это класс-предок объекта, всё как в ООП - разница только в том, что прототип в JS - это уже сконструированный "готовый" объект, а в классическом ООП "прототип" - неотделим от самого класса-потомка: то есть не является ни объектом, ни чем-либо "физическим". Как работает наследование в JS, аналогичное обычному ООП наследованию - легко понять по такому примеру:

```js
var classA = function(){this.x = function(){ this.a++; return this.a; } };

var classB = function(){ this.a = 2;};
classB.prototype = new classA();

console.log((new classB) instanceof classA);
console.log((new classB).x());
```

3. Разве что прототипы могут больше, чем могут классы - например прототип(класс-предок говоря языком ООП) можно поменять/установить как для одного объекта, так и для класса в целом во время выполнения. Например можно типу-числу (Number) добавить поведение функции (вызов через скобки), см. [скрещивание ужей с ежами в MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf#First_example_Appending_a_chain_to_a_prototype). Где вы видели, чтоб в ООП можно было на лету подменить класс-предок?) При операции установки прототипа - происходит тоже самое, что произошло бы при подмене базового класса: а именно все свойства/методы объекта, не найденные у себя - ищутся уже в другом классе-предке, логика изменяется. Собственно эта возможность подмены/установки базового класса - и является главной фишкой прототипного программирования.
4. Если нужно вызывать метод класса родителя, при том что он переопределён в текущем классе: до ES6 (в котором есть `super`) можно было делать так `this.__proto__.someMethod.apply(this, [arg1, arg2]);` . Длиннее, чем обычно в ООП - но суть остаётся той-же. Доступ к родительскому конструктору также имеется через  `this.__proto__.constructor.apply(this,[...])`. Указываю на это - т.к. не очевидно поначалу - и прототипы кажутся совсем унылыми в плане ООП.
5. ES6 и его синтаксис определения классов - это просто декорации старых добрых прототипов: то есть ничего принципиально нового в нём нет. Разве что ООП в JS стало удобнее. То есть ИМХО - `Прототипное программирование` это просто красное словцо. Ну да - нету `protected`, тоже сначала плевался, а потом понял что и не надо: инкапсуляция в JS очень красиво делается на замыканиях. Зато никто не мешает изобрести своё ООП если уж хочется(я бы не рекомендовал, но порой встечается в фреймворках), а также делать объекты мутанты - например массив может быть одновременно функцией через `setPrototypeOf` .

Как прототипы описаны в книжках и пособиях по JS дело другое: в ответе описана краткая помощь для разбора прототипов людям, знающим другие ООП-языки.

Comment: Надо переварить, всё же в Java всё это понятнее и логичнее выглядит как по моему..

Comment: @Maks.Burkov не берите в голову просто этот термин "прототипное программирование". Суть ответа в том, что оно мало отличается от ООП, является немного расширенным ООП но без инкапсуляции через private/protected . Кстати инкапсуляция в JS предполагается черз замыкания (вложенные функции) - что гораздо мощнее private/protected .

Comment: @Maks.Burkov  немного подправил ответ. Может быть что-то прояснит. Честно говоря меня тоже очень раздражал весь материал по прототипам JS после С++ , поэтому такой вот ответ - который искал сам когда-то

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр, уже не любая, к стрелочным функциям нельзя применять оператор new

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, поправлю.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему прототипное программирование очень просто для понимания. У тебя есть совокупность объектов и одни из них наследуют свойства или методы других. Вот и всё, тут просто не появляется лишняя сущность "класс".

*"это модель ООП которая не использует классы, а вместо этого сначала выполняет поведение класса"* - а это неправильный перевод вот этого фрагмента:

> Prototype-based programming is an OOP model that doesn't use classes,
>   but rather it first accomplishes the behavior of any class and then
>   reuses it (equivalent to inheritance in class-based languages) by
>   decorating (or expanding upon) existing prototype objects.

Впрочем, тут и в оригинале заумно написано.